# C - Weird 2d Array pointer behaviour

Tags: c, arrays

I having a problem while passing a 2d array to a function. Have a look at the code-:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void display(int (*arr)[3],int i,int j,int length,int breadth) {

    for(;i<length;i++){
            for(;j<breadth;j++){
                printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    int arr[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    display(arr,0,0,3,3);
    }
```

When I run this code I can only get the first row of the 2D array printed. But when do not use i and j from the formal argument and instead declare them as local variables within the *display()* function everything works fine. Why can't I use the local values passed to function directly ?
I am using the **Visual C++ command line compiler in Visual Studio 2013**.

Comment: i and j are passed by value into the function.  You can't change them (you can, but behavior is undefined).

Comment: This is the weirdest way of writing loops. Also, you don't need to pass `breadth`, because it's implied in the type of the inner array (`int[3]`) and queryable.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: That sounds completely made up.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Huh? Using function parameters as local variables isn't undefined behavior. You can modify them all you want, keeping in mind the variables are locally scoped within the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With what you are doing, when will j get reset to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You miss temporary variable for your loop:

```
int tj;

for(;i<length;i++)
{
    for(tj=j;tj<breadth;tj++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i][tj]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`j` need to initialized after increment of `i`.

```
for(j=0;j<breadth;j++){
```